# Handling POST requests using Apache's mod_proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am currently hosting 2 web applications on the same Apache server.  Let's just call, them A and B.  I was using JSONP to make cross domain ajax calls from A to B (I needed some data from B).  The problem became apparent with this method when my request got too big and GET simply wouldn't work; I needed to use a POST request.

I installed mod_proxy and configured my Apache web server to act as a reverse proxy as illustrated here: http://bit.ly/rpeWJI .  This worked beautifully with GET requests, but I am still unable to get POST requests to work properly.  Can someone help me?

As a side note, I am using the Pylons web framework for my web applications.

Comment: Ack!  Sorry for this post.....I had a bad url call.  Programmer error.

Comment: so, were you able to get the POST working with only Apache? how did you do it? thanks.

Comment: Hi spli19, I just saw your post today.  This was last year.  I recently had to do this kind of behaviour again and realized that there's actually a much easier and better way to do this with POST requests.  I strongly recommend using the Requests module to make post requests to another server.  The requests module can be found here, it's super easy to use:  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

May I suggest using [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) instead of Apache. [Here](http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample) is an example config:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m
                                        inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass             http://1.2.3.4;
            proxy_set_header       Host $host;
            proxy_cache            STATIC;
            proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                                  http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for this.  I'll consider this for my next web application.

Comment: I've been wanting to try out nginx for some time.  Looks really neat.

Comment: Well, not everyone is able to switch to the goodies of nginx and the question was about Apache. So an answer like that is very confusing and certainly not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have mod_security enabled in Apache?

I came across your post while debugging why HTTP POST requests were failing against my reverse proxy. (They were receiving a 403 response).

It turned our the server was using mod_security with OWASP settings. Monitoring the error log and then adding `application/json` to the list of approved types solved it.

I also had to allow `PUT` requests for similar reasons.